# Connect Android Tablets via cable/wire

Tags: android, android-networking

I have 6 android tablets, and i want to connect them via a cable/wire, so that they can send messages to one another. (perhaps similar to way PCs may be networked with each other)

Once connected, apps running on the devices can exchange messages with each other via sockets or any other protocol. What are the best options?

Connecting devices over wi-fi is an option too, but then internet is not guaranteed in this scenario, and devices may be very far of from each other for any near field communication.

Answer (score 0):

You can use usb->ethernet adapters and connect via LAN

Comment: ligi> How do i send message to a 'particular' android device?

Answer (score 0):

> Connecting devices over wi-fi is an option too, but then internet is
>   not guaranteed in this scenario, and devices may be very far of from
>   each other for any near field communication.

as long as all your devices and server (if any) are on same LAN or simply everything is connected to same hotspot you need not to worry about internet